# Wpf custom datepicker user control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, xaml-binding

I want to create a user control for getting a date from the user.  It should have three textboxes, one for year, month and day.  I don't know how to create it.

```
<UserControl x:Class="UI.WPF.CustomControls.ChooseDateControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         x:Name="chooseDateControl"
         xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:UI.WPF.CustomControls"
         d:DesignHeight="26" d:DesignWidth="181" FontFamily="Tahoma">

<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="14" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="14" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Label Content="/" Grid.Column="1" />
        <Label Content="/" Grid.Column="3" />

        <custom:NumericTextBox x:Name="txtYear" ToolTip="سال" Text="{Binding ElementName=chooseDateControl, Mode=TwoWay, Path=Year}" MaxLength="4" TabIndex="2" MinWidth="20" />
        <custom:NumericTextBox x:Name="txtMonth" Grid.Column="2" ToolTip="ماه" Text="{Binding ElementName=chooseDateControl, Mode=TwoWay, Path=Month}" MaxLength="2" TabIndex="1" MinWidth="20" />
        <custom:NumericTextBox x:Name="txtDay" Grid.Column="4" ToolTip="روز" Text="{Binding ElementName=chooseDateControl, Mode=TwoWay, Path=Day}" MaxLength="2" TabIndex="0" MinWidth="20" />
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

**Code Behind**

```
public partial class ChooseDateControl : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty YearProperty;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MonthProperty;
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DayProperty;

    static ChooseDateControl()
    {
        ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Value",
            typeof(DateTime), typeof(ChooseDateControl),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(DateTime.MinValue));

        ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Year",
            typeof(int), typeof(ChooseDateControl),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((int)0));

        ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Month",
            typeof(int), typeof(ChooseDateControl),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((int)0));

        ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Day",
            typeof(int), typeof(ChooseDateControl),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((int)0));
    }

    public ChooseDateControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public DateTime Value
    {
        get
        {
            return (DateTime)base.GetValue(ValueProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            base.SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public int Year
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)base.GetValue(YearProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            base.SetValue(YearProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public int Month
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)base.GetValue(MonthProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            base.SetValue(MonthProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public int Day
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)base.GetValue(DayProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            base.SetValue(DayProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't work correctly-- it returns the default value, which is DateTime.MinValue.  Please help me.

Comment: You still need to fix your property registrations.  You are registering everything to the ValueProperty.  make sure you change to set the YearProperty, MonthyProperty, etc...

Comment: There are aslo some problems with the logic to set the values, which for one you are never setting the Value property.  You may want to look at the DatTimeUpDown control in the Extended WPF Toolkit to see how it is handled there: http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/

Comment: I am asuming you want to use the Value property as the property that is used for the databinding.  This means you will have to handle the property changted call basck for the Value property to set the other property values. In the other propert callbacks you will probably want to set the Value property using the new D/M/Y combinations.

Answer (score 1):

It might be better writing the logic kind of like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Year");
    var year = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Month");
    var month = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("Day");
    var day = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    var customDate = new DateTime(year, month, day);

    Console.WriteLine(customDate);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

You could implement something similar like having a button that when pressed will get the values and create a new datetime value. There are many ways of generating a DateTime from input values just surf the web and you will find a ton of examples and tutorials about this in WPF. Hopefully this will give you some idea's and help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the `Calendar` or `DatePicker` controls in the [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535)? You haven't mentioned anything in your question that is custom, so this should work ok for you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have your text boxes wired up to your dependency property.  The value is never set.  You need some type of converter that will convert the values in your text boxes to an actual date too. I think you are better off going with the `DatePicker` Control in the toolkit (3.5) or the framework (4.0).

Comment: thanks for answer - because datepicker has not the persian date and for other reasons. please help. i edit the code, please see it again

Comment: So what happens now with the updated code?  Have you stepped into the control via the debugger?  Are your properties being set?  You can also use Snoop to see if you have any binding errors and to see what the data context is set to.

Comment: the result is DateTime.MinValue

Answer (score 0):

For starters stop copying and pasting :0).  All your DP registrations are for the `ValueProperty`.  And you will have to handle the property changed callback for each property to update the Value property as well.